# How to get Account Name from Google AuthToken

Tags: android, authentication

I use AccountManager in an Android App. The user signs in and I get the authtoken.
I would like to pass this token to a web server and have the web server retrieve the account name of the user based on the authtoken.
How do I do that on the server side? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What kind of token are you using? (ClientLogin, OAuth)? The account name may or may not be in the token, and if it is a proprietary one (ClientLogin), you won't know the actual format. So simply pass the account *and* the token to your web service.

Comment: The question is not about knowing what the user name is (this is easy as I get the user name on my Android), but authorizing the user on the server. I don't see any ways to use the token received with "ah" type on my server. Google responds "not authorized" to any attempts of using the token.

Comment: 'ah' is for App Engine. You can use the App Engine Users API to get the logged in user name. And yes, what you are asking is not that clear from the original question.